# Text with URL showing as delivered, but message not received - Twilio

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I'm working on an application that can automatically send out texts to members via Twilio. I need to include a URL in the message body, however, while the Twilio logs are showing the message as either 'sent' or 'delivered', I have not received the text on either of my 2 devices (Galaxy s10 and Galaxy s21, both on T-Mobile). The calls to send a message *do work* when I include a `mediaUrl` or a `body` without a URL (I've tested multiple messages with and without a URL), however I just haven't received a single message with a URL in the message body.

```
let twilioConfig = {
    body: `RSVP Link: <Some text>`, from: <fromPhoneNumber>, to: <toPhoneNumber>, mediaUrl: mediaLocationUrl
};

twilioClient.messages
    .create(twilioConfig)
    .then(message => console.log(message.sid)).catch((err) => {
        console.log("Ran into error while dispatching text through twilio");
        console.log(err);
        console.log("\n\n");
    });
```

If my `twilioConfig.body` has a URL, an `sid` will print to the console, no error will be printed, and the Twilio logs will show as delivered, however neither of my phones actually receive any messages. If I remove the url (and keep literally every other piece of text there), and send the message, I will receive it seconds later, also sometimes showing as 'sent' and sometimes showing as 'delivered' in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You might be experiencing carrier filtering. In this case, this is not something we can fix on Stack Overflow.

You should get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and provide them with example message SIDs for messages that didn't arrive. They will be able to check in to see what happened and make suggestions to avoid this.